# Limit value of a variable to a finite set of Strings?

Tags: javascript

In my code, I have a few "modes" of operation. Let's just call them "mode1", "mode2", and "mode3".

I want to be able to change and access the current mode from different parts of the code.

I could just assign the mode to a variable as a string. For instance:

```
var mode = "mode1";
...
if (mode === "mode3") {
    ...
}
```

... and so on.
However, I want to be sure that I'm not accidentally setting the value of the mode to something out-of-range like "mode4" or something completely unacceptable like "asdf". I want to limit the value of the variable to the finite set of Strings: {"mode1", "mode2", "mode3"}

What is the best way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You could have a function that is the only way to set the mode. The function can perform the necessary validation (this could be paired with a getter function which would be the only way to get the current mode).

Answer (score 1):

One possible option I came up with is to create a wrapper class:

```
function Mode() {
    var possibleModes = ["mode1", "mode2", "mode3"];
    var currentMode = possibleModes[0]; //default

    this.setMode = function(mode) {
        // Only set value if mode is in finite set of possible modes
        if (possibleModes.indexOf(mode) != -1) {
            currentMode = mode;
            return true;
        } else {
            throw "Cannot assign out-range-value mode";
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.getMode = function() {
        return currentMode;
    }
}

var mode = new Mode();
```

So that...

```
mode.setMode("asdf"); // error
mode.setMode("mode2"); // success
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
function Mode() {
    var possibleModes = ["mode1", "mode2", "mode3"];
    var currentMode = possibleModes[0];

    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {
        get: function(){
            return currentMode;
        },
        set: function(mode){
            if (possibleModes.indexOf(mode) !== -1) {
                currentMode = mode;
            } else {
                throw "Cannot assign out-range-value mode";
            }
        }
    })
};

var mode = new Mode();
```

So that...

```
mode.value = "asdf"; // error
mode.value = "mode2"; // success
```